# Is there a way to replace only once if possible by trying the rules sequentially in order?

Tags: replacement

Is there a `ReplaceOnce` which does only one replacement if possible by trying the rules sequentially in order. Consider the following as an example:

```
ReplaceOnce[{"May","5","May","5"},{"May"->1,"5"->2}]
```

should produce:

```
{1,"5","May","5"}
```

Similarly,

```
ReplaceOnce[{"May","5","May","5"},{"5"->2,"May"->1}]
```

should produce:

```
{"May",2,"May","5"}
```

Comment: I think it it not easy to determint the level of the tree structue. For example, `Replace[{"May", "5", "May", 
  "5", {"May", "5", "May", "5"}, {{"May", "5", "May", "5"}}}, {"May" ->
    1, "5" -> 2}, 2]`

Comment: May be `ReplacePart[{"May", "5", "May", "5"}, 
 Position[{"May", "5", "May", "5"}, "May"][[1]] -> 1]`

Comment: So to be clear, do you want to provide a list of rules and only apply the first one? Or only apply the first valid one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ClearAll[replace1ce]
replace1ce = Block[{$done = False}, 
    Fold[ReplaceAll, #, # :> RuleCondition[$done = True; #2, ! $done] & @@@ #2]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
replace1ce[{"May", "5", "May", "5"}, {"May" -> 1, "5" -> 2}]
```

> ```
> {1, "5", "May", "5"}
> ```

```
replace1ce[{"May", "5", "May", "5"}, {"5" -> 2, "May" -> 1}]
```

> ```
> {"May", 2, "May", "5"}
> ```

```
replace1ce[{"May", "5", "May", "5"}, {"blah" -> 10, "5" -> 2, "May" -> 1}]
```

> ```
> {"May", 2, "May", "5"}
> ```

```
replace1ce[{"May", "5", "May", "5"}, {"x" -> 10, s_String :> ToUpperCase[s], "5" -> 2}]
```

> ```
> {"MAY", "5", "May", "5"}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

I believe a better solution exists.

```
ClearAll[replaceLimitedBack, replaceLimited];

replaceLimitedBack[expr_, rulesRaw_, n_Integer, levelSpec_] := 
 Block[{rules = Association[rulesRaw], one = 0},
  {Replace[expr, 
    a_?(If[one < n && KeyExistsQ[rules, #], one += 1; True, 
         False] &) :> rules[a], levelSpec], n - one}]

replaceLimited[expr_, rulesRaw_List, n_Integer : 1, levelSpec_ : Infinity] := 
 First[Fold[
   replaceLimitedBack[#1[[1]], #2, #1[[2]], levelSpec] &, {expr, n}, 
   rulesRaw]]
```

In the condition (`?`), we check how many times we have replaced elements using `one` + if a replacement exists with `KeyExistsQ`, then increase the `one`.

result:

```
replaceLimited[{"May", "5", "May", "5"}, {"May" -> 1, "5" -> 2}]

(*Out: {1, "5", "May", "5"} *)


replaceLimited[{"May", "5", "May", "5"}, {"May" -> 1, "5" -> 2}, 2]

(*Out: {1, "5", 1, "5"} *)


replaceLimited[{"May", "5", "May", "5"}, {"5" -> 2, "May" -> 1}]

(*Out: {"May", 2, "May", "5"} *)
```

Notes:

- Rules will be applied one by one, as far as permitted. For example, if the limit is 2 and the first rule occurred 2 times, only the first rule will be applied and the rest of the rules will not be touched (see the second example).
- The third argument (`n`) is for how many times you want to replace.
- The fourth argument (`levelSpec`) is for Replace `LevelSpec`.

Comment: Does `replaceLimited[{"May","5","May","5"},{"5"->2,"May"->1}]` produces the desired result? The order part is also important.

Comment: @user13892 See the updated solution.

Answer (score 4):

There is probably a build in way. Too many commands and too little time :)

But you could always code one yourself.

```
ClearAll[replaceOnce]
replaceOnce[lis_List, rules_List] := Module[{lisin = lis, n, pos},
  Do[
   pos = FirstPosition[lis, rules[[n, 1]]] ;
   If[Not[Head[pos] === Missing],
    lisin = ReplacePart[lisin, pos -> rules[[n, 2]]];
    If[Not[SameQ[lisin, lis]],
     Return[lisin, Module]
     ]
    ],
   {n, 1, Length[rules]}
   ];
  lis
  ]
```

And now

```
lis = {"May", "5", "May", "5"};
rules1 = {"May" -> 1, "5" -> 2};
rules2 = {"5" -> 2, "May" -> 1};
rules3 = {"x" -> 2};
replaceOnce[lis, rules1]

(* {1, "5", "May", "5"} *)

replaceOnce[lis, rules2]

(* {"May",2,"May","5"} *)


 replaceOnce[lis, rules3]

(* {"May","5","May","5"} *)
```

Comment: It might be better to apply the replacement rule using `MapAt[Replace[rules[[n]]], lisin, pos]`, to make sure that stuff like `x_Integer :> x^2` works

Answer (score 3):

One approach (maybe not suited to your problem) is to use as pattern the whole expression instead of the elements of the expression. For example :

```
Replace[
{"May","5","May","5"}
,{{a___,"May",b___} :> {a,1,b}}
,{0}]
```

returns :

> {1, "5", "May", "5"}

With your example, it becomes a bit complex:

```
Replace[
 {"May","5","May","5"}
 , {
     {a___,"May",b___}:>{a,1,b}
    ,{a___,"5",b___}:>{a,2,b}
   }
 ,{0}]
```

> {1, "5", "May", "5"}

or the alternative :

```
Replace[
  {"May","5","May","5"}
  ,{{a___,x:("May"| "5"),b___}:>{a,x /. {"May"-> 1,"5"->2},b}}
  ,{0}]
```

> {1, "5", "May", "5"}